# getting text from textfield java fxml

Tags: java, fxml

Here is my fxml code and Java controller file code. I am trying to get the text from the TEXTFIELD tf in the handle event using "String s = tf.getText().toString();" but it is not getting executed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id = "aPane" prefHeight="268.0" prefWidth="379.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="sample.searchController">
  <children>
  <VBox layoutX="20.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="232.0" prefWidth="333.0">
     <children>
        <HBox prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="333.0">
           <children>
              <Label fx:id= "kw" text="Key Word : ">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                 </padding>
              </Label>
              <TextField fx:id="tf" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
              <Button fx:id="srch" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" text="Search" >
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </Button>
           </children>
           <padding>
              <Insets left="6.0" top="6.0" />
           </padding>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets />
           </VBox.margin>
           <opaqueInsets>
              <Insets />
           </opaqueInsets>
        </HBox>
        <TextArea fx:id="ta" prefHeight="174.0" prefWidth="282.0" />
     </children>
  </VBox>
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

JAVA controller Code :

```
public class searchController implements Initializable,EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

  AnchorPane aPane = new AnchorPane();
  Label kw = new Label();
  public TextField tf;
  Button srch = new Button();
  TextArea ta = new TextArea();
  //Text t;
  String s = "priyam";

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tf = new TextField();
  }

  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    s=tf.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `initialize()` actually overrides the value of `tf`. It Initialize your `TextField` Object `tf` with new Object.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  tf = new TextField();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your initialize method

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    tf = new TextField();
}
```

In this method you set tf to be a new text field. Thats an issue because when the fxml document is constructed the document builder will automatically populate that field with the textfield it constructs. But then your initialize method overwrites it with a blank one. So when you to tf.getText() your not getting the text from the one in the UI, your getting it from a blank one you created yourself. If you simply comment out `tf = new TextField();`it works fine.